# Can [My]SQL combine multiple overlapping composite indexes?

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing

Basically, if I have a table with composite indices (colA, colB, colC) and (colB, colD, colE), is MySQL able to take advantage of their overlap on colB to combine them and speed up a query involving colA, colB and colD, even if there is no single index covering these three particular columns?

I tried using EXPLAIN on a test case like this, but even though it recognized both indices as possible keys, it only used the first one. However, I do not know if this was because it is unable to make the combination or because the optimizer didn't think it was worth it given the number of rows.

I would expect it should be able to, but couldn't find any straight confirmation around. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any definitive answer either, but I think the answer is that it depends on the query and the data in the tables.  A multiple-column index can be used if the query refers to any of the left-most columns.  With your `(ColA, ColB, ColC)` index, the index may be used for queries which refer to `(ColA)`, `(ColA, ColB)` or `(ColA, ColB, ColC)`.  The same principle is true for your other index.

When two separate indexes are available, the MySQL optimizer will choose between performing an intersection based on both indexes, or using a single index, and filtering out the remaining results.  I suspect that the same will be true if both those separate indexes are multi-column indexes, and if the query refers to the left-most part of the indexes (as your example does with `ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD`.

You might find these links of use (but I don't think any of them will provide a definitive answer):

**MySQL Manual**
[Multiple-Column Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)
[How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html)

**MySQL Performance Blog**
[Multi Column indexes vs Index Merge](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/19/multi-column-indexes-vs-index-merge/)

Comment: This page seems to back you up: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html It says that versions of MySQL before 5.0 wouldn't use multiple indexes. But now, clearly, it can use more than one index in certain situations. I wonder whether it might take quite a large table for MySQL to decide to bother performing index-merges.